# clearTimeout() doesn't do what it's supposed to do

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

can anyone see what is wrong with the following code. it's supposed to display a count down from 30 and afterwards it refreshes the page with jquery's ajax `load()` function.

it works fine for the first or second count down but then the timer starts too count down to fastand sometimes goes to the negative numbers and does not stop at all

what am i doing wrong?

```
function refreshPage(){
    stopRefresh();
    $('div.yui-content').load('rdPage.aspx div.yui-content', doCalculation);
}

function stopRefresh(){
    clearTimeout(timer);
    clearTimeout(interval);
}

var count, timer, interval;

function startTimer(){
    count = 30;
    timer = setTimeout(refreshPage,count * 1000);
    interval= setInterval(updateTimer,1000);
}
function updateTimer(){
    count --;
    $('#timerSpan').text("Refreshing in " + count + "s");
}


function doCalculation(){
    negativeNumberRed();
    startTimer();

}
```

edit: added `doCalculations()`

Comment: Where is the `doCalculation` function?

Comment: Something makes me think that you're not showing us all the code here ...  Where do you **call** "startTimer()", and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a call to "stopRefresh()" to the "startTimer()" call.

```
function startTimer(){
    stopRefresh();
    count = 30;
    timer = setTimeout(refreshPage,count * 1000);
    interval= setInterval(updateTimer,1000);
}
```

My guess is that your code is managing to start up more than one instance of the interval timer. They'll all decrement the same counter.

*edit* — oops - Dr. Strangelove is correct - you need to use "clearInterval()" on interval timers, and "clearTimeout()" for timeout timers. (*edit again* well, you probably *should* do that, but Chrome at least seems to stop interval timers via "clearTimeout()". [Here is the jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/ZLtZc/)

Answer (score 6):

try
`clearInterval(interval);` instead of `clearTimeout(interval);`

Like this:

```
function stopRefresh(){
    clearTimeout(timer);
    clearInterval(interval);
}
```

Comment: Sorry Doctor, I didn't mean to steal your thunder - this is a very important point!!

Comment: ... although Chrome, at least, seems to clear an interval timer with "clearTimeout()" too, which is a little disconcerting.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better to only use the interval..
And when the `count < 1` call  refreshPage